# How to create a ribbon shape in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

http://jsfiddle.net/6HyjZ/

```
.bookmarkRibbon{
     width:0; 
     height:100px; 
     border-right:50px solid blue;
     border-left:50px solid blue;
     border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
}

<div class="bookmarkRibbon"></div>
```

I'm struggling to make a version of this shape where the ribbon is pointing right instead of down, 
how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Ribbon shape using CSS **[Clip Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)**:

```css
.bookmarkRibbon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 20px) 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bookmarkRibbon"></div>
```

Pointing down:

```css
.bookmarkRibbon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 50% calc(100% - 20px), 0% 100%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bookmarkRibbon"></div>
```

### Ribbon shape using CSS [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

To help you visualize the logic **step-by-step**, so you can apply it easily on **any side**:

[image: CSS Ribbon Shape - How To Create]

```css
.bookmarkRibbon {
  border:       30px solid blue;        /* All borders set */
  border-left:  0;                      /* Remove left border */
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; /* Right transparent */
  width:        100px;                  /* Increase element Width */
}
```

```html
<div class="bookmarkRibbon"></div>
```

Comment: Not only is this the best answer of this question, this is the best answer I've ever seen on this forum in general

Comment: very well explained! TY!

Answer (score 4):

Using the helpful accepted answer here is it with text version.

**Vertical(Top to bottom) Banner with text**

```css
.ribbon-vertical {
 position: absolute;
 right: 10px;
   border:       13px solid #e46a76;        /* All borders set */
   border-top:  0;                      /* Remove left border */
   border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; /* Right transparent */
   height: auto;                  /* Increase element Width */
   width: 0;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   color: white;
   z-index: 1;
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
      filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}

.ribbon-vertical div{
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon-vertical"><div>BANNER</div></div>
```

**Horizontal(Right to Left) Banner with text**

```css
.ribbon-horizontal{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 5rem;
   border: 13px solid #e46a76;
   border-right: 0;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   height: 0;
   line-height: 0;
   width: 100px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 1;
   -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
      filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.ribbon-horizontal span{
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 4px 0 10px;
 text-align: center;      
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon-horizontal"><span>BANNER</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bookmarkRibbon{
     width:100px; 
     height:0; 
     border-bottom:50px solid blue;
     border-top:50px solid blue;
     border-right:30px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you 'rotate' the css properties, it rotates the form by 90 degrees.

```
.bookmarkRibbon{
     width:100px; 
     height:0; 
     border-bottom:50px solid blue;
     border-top:50px solid blue;
     border-left:30px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6HyjZ/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform:rotate` :

```
.bookmarkRibbon{
     width:0; 
     height:100px; 
     border-right:50px solid blue;
     border-left:50px solid blue;
     border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just swap what you have and you are good to go [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGJBL/):

```
.bookmarkRibbonRight{
     width:100px; 
     height:0px; 
     border-right:30px solid transparent;
     border-bottom:50px solid blue;
     border-top:50px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You already have the shape, just use the transform property to change its angle.

Here is the code that I have added to the code you have.

```
 transform: rotate(270deg);
```

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/6HyjZ/11/ It now points to the right (unless that's right **right** side)

Comment: he's just *struggling to make a version of this shape where the ribbon is pointing right instead of down* so it's achievable in pure CSS2 (IE8 friendly)

Answer (score -2):

Use the `rotate` css transform:

```
 .bookmarkRibbon{
      width:0; 
      height:100px; 
      border-right:50px solid blue;
      border-left:50px solid blue;
      border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6HyjZ/13/