# I want to make a small vertical line at left of the border of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, visual-web-developer

If you are unable to understand, then please open the image. I want to draw a black vertical line at left border of a div

I apologise for my useless paint ability.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YGpU.png)
What must I do to make this in css?.

Thanks.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML Code

```html
<div class="badge">
    <p class="text">New</p>
</div>
```

CSS for background

```css
.badge {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 65%, 0 100%);
    background-color : red;
    height: 100px;
    width:50px
}
.text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 35px;
}
```

You can use [bennettfeely](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) for diffrent css shapes that will generate a clip-path of the shape

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207393/10293708, has a similar question. But all in all, I would also suggest you to do try out doing something using css first and maybe you could add a jsfiddle link to what you have achieved so far, so that others can help better.